# Is there any way to create a stripe payment link with the email field fulfilled?

Tags: stripe-payments

First of all, I have already read the Stripe [Payment links](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links) docs.

A bit of context: I want to create a subscription product. I do not want to integrate the Stripe API so I have decided to use payment links so the users will be redirected to an Stripe payment page where they can finish the payment.

I already have the user email so I want that they have the email field fulfilled when they enter this page. Is there any way to achieve this? Maybe with a query param or something.

Thanks!

[image: Stripe form screenshot]

Comment: sure, it seems now it is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PaymentLinks [support a URL parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links#url-parameters), `prefilled_email`, to pre-fill a customer’s email on the payment view.

Here’s an example:
https://buy.stripe.com/test_cN25mc5wh1Kt6tO8wS?prefilled_email=test@email.com

Comment: sure, I don't know how I didn't see that. Thanks!